# ListView slide out effect like Cocktail Flow

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I really think that [Cocktail Flow](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/de-at/app/cocktail-flow/88e08b7c-10d0-45b8-9280-946bd889e243) is one of the best `Windows Store Apps` regarding design. They've implemented a `ListView` with cocktails and when you select one cocktail the other cocktails fly out to the left and right of the screen. `Ingredients` and `preparation` steps for the selected cocktail then fly in.

How would you make such a nice effect?

Any code examples or hints are well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you've already taken a look at page and content transitions?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452701.aspx

Comment: Yes, I've tried the `RepositionThemeAnimation` but I couldn't recreate the Cocktail Flow effect.